# Can I make a recyclerview without an xml layout for the ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm putting a `RecyclerView` in my android app. So, like in all the documentation I've seen for recycler views, I have an `Adapter` class with a `ViewHolder` class defined inside it. That code is shown below (in `PointChangeAdapter.java`).

However, there is one difference between my code and most of the tutorials I've seen;
I do not have an `xml` file defining a layout for my `ViewHolder`. At least that's what I'm trying to get working.

It seems I shouldn't need to define a custom layout, because the elements of my `RecyclerView` are just `TextView`s. This could probably be done with a ListView, but I like the flexibility of `RecyclerView`, and also just want to understand if it is possible to get what I have here working. That is, *with* the recycler and *without* the `xml` layout.

To accommodate the lack of `xml` layout, I have modified my Adapter's `onCreateViewHolder` method.
Where a typical example would use a layout inflater, e.g.

```
    @Override
    public PointChangeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final TextView textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_viewholder_xml_layout, parent, false);
        return new PointChangeViewHolder(textView);
    }
```

I instead have

```
    @Override
    public PointChangeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        parent.addView(textView);
        return new PointChangeViewHolder(textView);
    }
```

That is, instead of calling `inflate` on an xml layout and specifying the `RecyclerView` parent,
I create a new `TextView` and add it directly to the `RecyclerView` parent via `addView`.

Only problem is this does not work.

It gives me a "ViewHolder views must not be attached when created" error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.mherzl.pointcounter, PID: 5253
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the
> attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean
> attachToRoot)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7080)
>
> ...

I have also tried removing the `parent.addView(textView);` line entirely,
making my example almost identical to [this](https://gist.github.com/sheharyarn/3be170d07d508fa6228320ad49064c2b) example,
which, like I am trying to do, does not specify an `xml` layout.
When I run my code without the `addView` line, I do not get the error,
but in that case the text still does not show up in the recycler views.
So something appears wrong then as well.
Also, I feel that the `addView` line should be needed;
since the inflater appears to attach the `TextView` to the `RecyclerView` parent,
it seems that what I replace the inflater with should attach to it as well.

Is it possible to make a `RecyclerView` using `TextView`s as elements
instead of an element defined by a custom xml layout?

Here is my code:

`PointChangeAdapter.java`:

```
package com.mherzl.pointcounter;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class PointChangeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PointChangeAdapter.PointChangeViewHolder> {

    private List<Integer> recentChanges;

    public PointChangeAdapter(List<Integer> recentChanges) {
        this.recentChanges = recentChanges;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (recentChanges == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return recentChanges.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PointChangeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        parent.addView(textView);
        return new PointChangeViewHolder(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PointChangeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int pointChange = recentChanges.get(position);
        String text = Integer.toString(pointChange);
        holder.setText(text);
    }

    public static class PointChangeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;

        public PointChangeViewHolder(TextView textView) {
            super(textView);
            this.textView = textView;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what runs it -- in the `onCreateView` of the fragment using the `RecyclerView`:

```
RecyclerView pointChangeRecycler =
        (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.point_changes_recycler);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
pointChangeRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(1); myList.add(2); myList.add(3);
PointChangeAdapter pointChangeAdapter = new PointChangeAdapter(myList);
pointChangeRecycler.setAdapter(pointChangeAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  onCreateViewHolder just returns a ViewHolder with a ViewGroup (possibly even just a View) as the root view.

Your problem is that you added it to a parent.  You don't want to do that.  The RecyclerView will end up being its parent.  You should just be creating it and returning a holder with that view as the root view.

Yes, even though the parent passed in is probably (although not necessarily) also the RecyclerView.  The layout manager of the recycler view does the adding.  That's why the last parameter of your inflate() call is false-  to prevent inflate from adding it to a parent.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation Gabe, I will plan to remove the `parent.addView` line based on this answer. Do you have an idea of why the elements do not show up in the recycler view in that case? (With the `addView` line the app crashes, without it the app doesn't crash but the recycler appears to be empty)

Comment: It turned out the recycler view needed to be in a FrameLayout, I think that was my other issue.